# How to simulate an 8x4 memory using VHDL?

Tags: vhdl, simulation, memory, ise

Why does this code:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use ieee.numeric_std.ALL;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;

entity memorie8x4 is
        port(

        cs:             in std_logic; -- cs = 1 => chip selected
        rw:             in std_logic; -- rw = 1 => read; 0 => write
        address: in std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
        output:         inout std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) -- tip inout ca sa putem si citi si scrie

        );
end memorie8x4;

architecture Behavioral of memorie8x4 is

        type MEM_array is array(0 to 7) -- 3 biti de adresa
                of std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
        signal mem8x4: MEM_array := (others => "0000"); -- valorile noastre prestabilite

        signal out_sig: std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) := "ZZZZ";
begin
        -- este output doar cand suntem in read mode. Cand suntem in write mode e input
        -- ( starea Z e impedanta mare ca sa putem citi valori de la portul output )
        output <= out_sig when (cs = '1' and rw = '1') else (others => 'Z');

        process(cs, rw)
        begin
                if cs = '0' then
                        out_sig <= "ZZZZ";
                else -- chip-ul este selectat
                        if rw = '1' then --modul read a fost selectat
                                case address is
                                        when "000" => out_sig <= mem8x4(0);
                                        when "001" => out_sig <= mem8x4(1);
                                        when "010" => out_sig <= mem8x4(2);
                                        when "011" => out_sig <= mem8x4(3);
                                        when "100" => out_sig <= mem8x4(4);
                                        when "101" => out_sig <= mem8x4(5);
                                        when "110" => out_sig <= mem8x4(6);
                                        when "111" => out_sig <= mem8x4(7);
                                        when others => out_sig <= "0000";
                                end case;
                        else -- modul write a fost selectat
                                case address is
                                        when "000" => mem8x4(0) <= output;
                                        when "001" => mem8x4(1) <= output;
                                        when "010" => mem8x4(2) <= output;
                                        when "011" => mem8x4(3) <= output;
                                        when "100" => mem8x4(4) <= output;
                                        when "101" => mem8x4(5) <= output;
                                        when "110" => mem8x4(6) <= output;
                                        when "111" => mem8x4(7) <= output;
                                        when others => mem8x4 <= (others => "0000");
                                end case;
                        end if;
                end if;

        end process;

end Behavioral;
```

With this testbench:

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;

ENTITY mem8x4_tb IS
END mem8x4_tb;

ARCHITECTURE behavior OF mem8x4_tb IS

    -- Component Declaration for the Unit Under Test (UUT)

    COMPONENT memorie8x4
    PORT(
         cs : IN  std_logic;
         rw : IN  std_logic;
         address : IN  std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
         output : INOUT  std_logic_vector(3 downto 0)
        );
    END COMPONENT;


   --Inputs
   signal cs : std_logic := '0'; -- default neselectat
   signal rw : std_logic := '1'; -- default read mode
   signal address : std_logic_vector(2 downto 0) := (others => '0'); -- default adresa 0

   signal output : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) := "0000";

BEGIN

        -- Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
   uut: memorie8x4 PORT MAP (
          cs => cs,
          rw => rw,
          address => address,
          output => output
        );

   -- vreau sa citesc o valoare din memorie, dupa care sa inchid chip-ul,
        -- sa scriu o valoare in memorie, sa inchid chip-ul, sa trec in read
        -- si sa citesc daca valoarea a fost scrisa
        process
        begin

                wait for 10 ns;
                address <= "010"; -- selectez adresa
                rw <= '1'; -- trec in modul read
                cs <= '1'; -- activez memoria -> citesc output-ul
                wait for 10 ns;
                cs <= '0'; -- dezactivez memoria
                rw <= '0'; -- trec in modul write
                output <= "0110"; -- scriu ceva la output
                cs <= '1'; -- activez memoria, se scrie in memorie
                wait for 10 ns;
                cs <= '0'; -- dezactivez memoria
                rw <= '1'; -- trec in modul read
                address <= "001";
                cs <= '1';
                wait for 10 ns;
                address <= "010";
                --cs <= '1'; -- activez memoria, citesc valoarea de la output
                wait;
        end process;
END;
```

Not work the way it's supposed to? What am I doing wrong? This is how the simulation looks like:

[image: simulation]

Comment: You assigning an output with a value "output <= "0110";" which will cause the signal to go X when the memory starts driving it, remvoe that line, and let the memry drive the signal and remember that you NEVER drive an output from a module in your testbench.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look what's actually going on (with the VHDL code originally posted in the question):

[image: ![mem8x4_tb showing TB and UUT]
*(clickable)*

You'll see there are driver conflicts because `output` is actually mode inout and you're driving it constantly in the testbench.

If you simulate the new pastebin versions of your code with the clock you'll find the same conflict between the two drivers of `output`.

You're also apparently missing some delays preventing some of your signal conditions from taking affect.  I fixed those along with the driver conflicts in the following architecture:

```
architecture foo of mem8x4_tb is

    constant READ:      std_logic := '1';
    constant WRITE:     std_logic := '0';
    constant SELECTED:  std_logic := '1';
    constant DISABLED:  std_logic := '0';
    constant UNDRIVEN:  std_logic_vector (3 downto 0) := (others => 'Z');
    signal cs:          std_logic := DISABLED; 
    signal rw:          std_logic := READ; 
    signal address:     std_logic_vector(2 downto 0) := (others => '0'); 
    signal output:      std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
begin

UUT:
    entity work.memorie8x4 
        port map (
            cs => cs,
            rw => rw,
            address => address,
            output => output
        );

STIMULUS:
    process
    begin
        output <= UNDRIVEN;
        wait for 10 ns;
        address <= "010";
        rw <= READ;
        cs <= SELECTED;
        wait for 10 ns;
        cs <= DISABLED;
        rw <= WRITE;
        output <= "0110";
        wait for 10 ns;
        cs <= SELECTED;
        wait for 10 ns;
        cs <= DISABLED;
        rw <= READ;
        output <= (others => 'Z');
        wait for 10 ns;
        address <= "001";  
        cs <= SELECTED;
        wait for 10 ns;
        address <= "010";
        wait for 90 ns;
        wait;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

This also prompted adding address and output to the process sensitivity list in `memorie8x4`, which prompted getting rid of `out_sig`:

```
architecture foo of memorie8x4 is

    type MEM_array is array(0 to 7)  of std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    signal mem8x4: MEM_array := (others => "0000");
begin

    process(cs, rw, address, output)
    begin
        if cs = '0' then
            output <= "ZZZZ";
        else 
            if rw = '1' then  -- READ
                case address is
                    when "000" => output <= mem8x4(0);
                    when "001" => output <= mem8x4(1);
                    when "010" => output <= mem8x4(2);
                    when "011" => output <= mem8x4(3);
                    when "100" => output <= mem8x4(4);
                    when "101" => output <= mem8x4(5);
                    when "110" => output <= mem8x4(6);
                    when "111" => output <= mem8x4(7);
                    when others => output <= "0000";
                end case;      
            else              -- WRITE
                case address is
                    when "000" => mem8x4(0) <= output;
                    when "001" => mem8x4(1) <= output;
                    when "010" => mem8x4(2) <= output;
                    when "011" => mem8x4(3) <= output;
                    when "100" => mem8x4(4) <= output;
                    when "101" => mem8x4(5) <= output;
                    when "110" => mem8x4(6) <= output;
                    when "111" => mem8x4(7) <= output;
                    when others => mem8x4 <= (others => "XXXX"); -- invalid addr
                end case;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

Note I also changed the value of an unknown address during a write to invalidate the entire memory, representing not knowing what the actual address written will be.

It would be unsafe to change `address` while `rw = '0'`, in an actual implementation the propagation delay of `address` elements might be long enough to cause erroneous writes.

And that gives:

[image: correct output bus operation, memory sensitivity]
*(clickable)*

Where you can see the write only occurred when `cs` enabled the memory and none of the addresses presented in the testbench have the incorrect memory value.

Answer (score 2):

Your process is sensitive to the changes in `cs` and `rw` only. The output is changing to unknown on the transition of `rw` from low to high with address which was never assigned. Therefore you are getting an unknown value. But then there are no more transitions of `cs` and `rw`, so the simulation is not executing that process again and not changing the output. Probably you might want to add the `address` to the sensitivity list as well.

Comment: Adding address doesn't change anything, unfortunately.

Comment: Are you getting the same waveforms?

Comment: Yup, adding a clock signal fixed it! Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Adding a clock signal like [this](http://pastebin.com/kywDt67Y) seems to work! [Testbench](http://pastebin.com/bwHtscru)